# I am getting ORA-00904 "Invalid Identifier" when I use a legitimate column name in a left join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, ora-00904

I am getting ORA-00904 "Invalid Identifier" when I use a legitimate column name in a left join, but I do not get an error using the same identifier (I copied and pasted to be sure) in the where clause if I use a standard (inner) join on the table I was trying to limit.

Example 1:

```
Select NAMES.R_NAME 
        From CMPLN, NAMES 
        Where CMPLN.CMPLN_ID = NAMES.CMPLN_ID
```

Works.

EXAMPLE 2:

```
 Select NAMES.R_NAME
      From CMPLN
      Left Join NAMES On CMPLN.CMPLN_ID = NAMES.CMPLN_ID
```

Gets an  error.

> "ORA-00904: "CMPLN"."CMPLN_ID": invalid identifier

I am using Oracle.

(From an answer posted by the asker Jul 29 '15 at 12:40 that should have been an edit:)

I didn't present the code correctly for the answer to be apparent.
I had inserted another table in the From clause between CMPLN and the join, like this:

```
Select NAMES.R_NAME
From CMPLN, RSPN
Left Join NAMES On CMPLN.CMPLN_ID = NAMES.CMPLN_ID
```

That is what caused the error.

(In the Informix SQL I am used to this would have worked, but not in Oracle.)

Comment: can you reproduce this error in sql fiddle?

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? Oracle 9 and 10 did have several bugs when using explicit JOINs especially when used inside VIEWs or MATERIALIZED VIEWs

Comment: this is might be some bug in the Oracle version you are using. Use Mention explicit alias name as then try agian `Select N.R_NAME
      From CMPLN C
      Left OUTER Join NAMES  N On C.CMPLN_ID = N.CMPLN_ID`

Comment: Seems to work OK in Oracle 11g R2 in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b6dd/2

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: If you had given a MCVE this would have been a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: `ORA-00904: "TTR"."PARENT_CNTL_NBR": invalid identifier` as per the below:

```
SELECT *
FROM TTR,
  TST
LEFT JOIN ITF
ON NVL(TRIM(TST.CLIENT_USE_TXT), TRIM(SUBSTR(TTR.PARENT_CNTL_NBR, 1, 22))) = NVL(TRIM(ITF.CLIENT_USE_TXT), TRIM(SUBSTR(ITF.TRANSACTION_NO, 1, 22)))
WHERE TST.SECURITY_ADP_NBR                                                 = TTR.SECURITY_ADP_NBR
```

I fixed it by having all joins done by the `join` clause rather than in a `where` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM TTR
INNER JOIN TST
ON TST.SECURITY_ADP_NBR = TTR.SECURITY_ADP_NBR
LEFT JOIN ITF
ON NVL(TRIM(TST.CLIENT_USE_TXT), TRIM(SUBSTR(TTR.PARENT_CNTL_NBR, 1, 22))) = NVL(TRIM(ITF.CLIENT_USE_TXT), TRIM(SUBSTR(ITF.TRANSACTION_NO, 1, 22)))
```